# Play framework DB schema evolution hangs when create index concurrently

Tags: postgresql, playframework

I need to add index to a column in a very large table.
To avoid locking the table, I tried to use `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`.

During the testing on a small dataset, I found that will lead the Play framework schema evolution to hang.After I removed the `CONCURRENTLY`, schema evolution can finish quickly.

Versions:

```
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.15",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-java" % "2.6.15",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY waiting column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889476/postgresql-create-index-concurrently-waiting-column)

Comment: @TimMoore 
so it is possible that the hanging is caused by idle connection. Let me do some investigation how to avoid idle connection Play framework's DB evolution.

Comment: We usually run such updates outside of Play Evolutions so that it doesn't block Play start or running queries. And then add a `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` to still track the change with evolutions.

Comment: @GaëlJ
We have a java cli tool (based on Play) evolve the schema, and I found this tool does not return and hanging forever.

I think you provide a good workaround: run the evolution directly through psql, and add the corresponding statement in Play evolution.